# How do non-reformed theologists argue against "God alone matters"?

Tags: reformed-theology

### Edit

For anyone that might stumble across this by accident:

This is not a position that reformed theologists hold. (I.e. my assumption is incorrect.)

### Original Question

If I understand reformed theologists correctly, reformed theology revolves around:

- God alone matters
- Everything for the glory of God.

Viewed from this perspective, how do non-reformed theologists argue against reformed theology?

NOTE: I understand this question is probably a bit too general. I would appreciate comments on how to narrow this.

Thanks!

Comment: The first is not something that Reformed theology asserts.  If it were so, God would not have created.

Comment: As Jon notes, the first statement here is not a doctrine held in any way by Reformed Theology. Putting God at the center of everything in no way implies that nothing outside of him has any significance. The only thing this is going to attract is people debunking a straw-man argument. Take out that issue and you're left with a _very_ broad question that isn't reasonably answerable in any meaningful way.

Comment: +1 for bothering to correct an incorrect assumption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matthew 22:37-40
King James Version (KJV)

> 37 Jesus said unto him, Thou shalt love the Lord thy God with all thy
>   heart, and with all thy soul, and with all thy mind.
>
> 38 This is the first and great commandment.
>
> 39 And the second is like unto it, Thou shalt love thy neighbour as
>   thyself.
>
> 40 On these two commandments hang all the law and the prophets.

I believe it is self explanatory that from the second commandment, we are to love ourselves and others as well.  Therefore, I believe this is a very locked-tight argument that all people matter, not just God.

This answer may not directly answer your actual question, because Reformist Theology may not assume God only matters, so the question may incorrect in its assumptions.  However, it does speak to the matter of whether only God matters.

Comment: This is not an argument against Reformed Theology since "only God matters" is not a position they hold.